# testName.getMethodName does not print when there are multiple @Test Annotations

Tags: java, junit

Method string works when there is only one Test annotation however does not when there are 5 or more Test annotations .

```
String BuildNumber = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.app-version.ng-binding")).getText();
System.out.println(" Test Case " + className + "  " + testName.getMethodName() + BuildNumber + " Date:  " + dateNow);
```

**Single Annotation Response**

```
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
Test Case CaseIni6_Empty5  Documents_C_Verify_Viewership_HR_RoleQA.730                    Date:  2017-08-01 09_25_48.029
User Name::HRCompanylevel
Password::XXXXXXXX
Finished Test Script
Finished Test Case
```

**Multiple Annotation Response**

```
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
Test Case QA_Regression  null Against Build-QA.730 Date:  2017-08-01            09_35_40.516
URL_STGE ::null
User Name::HRCompanylevel
Password::XXXXXX
```

Comment: Maybe the method name is modified by one of the annotations. Just guessing.

Comment: Please provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to reproduce the issue (including junit version), because it's near impossible to guess just from the description. It could be [a framework issue with parametrized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/892), something else or even _black magic_.